# Getting SolrQuery full query string

Tags: solr

i'm using Solrj in the dao tier of my application. What i want to know is how can i get

the full query string of the request.

For example:  `select?q=*:*&fq=active:true`

Method SolrQuery.getQuery() only returns the q=XXX part (`*:*` in my example)

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the proper environment to test it, but `SolrQuery.toString()` should get you close enough.

Comment: Thank you sir! You just saved my day! This works like expected!